# How to kill QThreadPool in pyside6

Tags: pyqt, pyside, pyside6

I'm working with PySide 6 and using QThreadPool for threading. I'm trying to figure out the best way to stop or interrupt a thread. I've noticed there isn't a direct terminate function for QThreadPool. I've attempted to use a condition to end the thread in a loop, but it seems to take too long inside the function. Any suggestions on how to handle this more effectively?

```
thread_manager = QThreadPool()


def run_inference():
    for num in(num_of_stream):
        if(status):
            break
        example()


thread_manager.start(run_inference)
```

I'm facing an issue with a long-running example() function within a thread. I attempted to use a 'stop button' that sets a status variable to 'false' when clicked, but it doesn't work effectively. The problem is that the example() function takes too long before moving to the next loop iteration. Is there a direct way to terminate the thread during the execution of example() or a more efficient alternative to handle this situation?

Comment: The example() function, is that your own code or code that you can modify? Is it loop based?

Comment: If the individual tasks in the loop aren't interruptible, you should consider using [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) instead.

Comment: @mahkitah nope the example() function is not my own code and i cant modify it

Comment: @ekhumoro i try change the code to something like this
`
thread_manager = Process(target=run_inference)

def run_inference():
    for num in(num_of_stream):
        if(status):
            break
        example()

thread_manager.start()

`
it give me error and my whole application unable to work 
`Abort was called at 52 line in file:
./shared/source/memory_manager/multi_graphics_allocation.cpp`
am i using it wrong like this?

Comment: @randompersonhehe If you want help, please edit your question and provide a proper [mre].